# CSS: Placing arrows (images) of a slideshow on top of it's inner elements

Tags: html, css

First I need to apologize for my weak English language.

I am making a slideshow using `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript` (but `JavaScrpt` isn't needed for this task). the issue is that when I resize the `window`, the arrows which are on the left and on the right are not above of the elements but it pushes the list item. To avoid confusion I have the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/george141/stfs382o/3/)

And the code used below:

```css
h1 {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 0px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.games-slideshow {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: red;
}
.games-slideshow .left-arrow {
 float: left;
 opacity: .5;
 margin-left: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 z-index: 9999;
}
.games-slideshow .right-arrow {
 float: right;
 opacity: .5;
 margin-right: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 z-index: 9999;
}
.games-slideshow .navigate {
 width: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
.games-slideshow .navigate ul {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
.games-slideshow .navigate ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
.games-slideshow .navigate ul li img {
 height: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: .5;
 transform: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.games-slideshow .navigate ul li img:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.games-slideshow .page1 {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 1200px;
 height: 60%;
 background-color: yellow;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0px;
}
.games-slideshow .page1 li {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%!important;
 max-width: 320px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: green;
 list-style: none;
}
.games-slideshow .page1 .not-last {
 margin-right: 12.15%;
}
.games-slideshow .page1 .last {
 margin-right: 0%!important;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="games-slideshow"> <img class="left-arrow" src="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFutureCompanyWebsite/images/leftSlideShowArrow.png"/> <img class="right-arrow" src="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFutureCompanyWebsite/images/rightSlideShowArrow.png"/>
  <div class="navigate">
    <ul>
      <li><img class="slideshow-circle" src="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFutureCompanyWebsite/images/slideshowCircle.png"/></li>
      <li><img class="slideshow-circle" src="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFutureCompanyWebsite/images/slideshowCircle.png"/></li>
      <li><img class="slideshow-circle" src="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFutureCompanyWebsite/images/slideshowCircle.png"/></li>
      <li class="last"><img class="slideshow-circle" src="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyFutureCompanyWebsite/images/slideshowCircle.png"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="page1">
    <li class="not-last">
      <div class="game">
        <p>Game Title</p>
        <a>More</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li class="not-last">
      <div class="game">
        <p>Game Title</p>
        <a>More</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
      <div class="game">
        <p>Game Title</p>
        <a>More</a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p id="debug"></p>
</body>
```

Try resizing the window to see the issue where the arrows push the list item. This is the issue I am facing. Does anyone know how can I make these arrows to not push or affect the elements inside the slideshow?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: Dude, you'll find plenty of examples for the same. The logic is simple: Put your arrows with absolute position to left and right of images' container. In your images' container, set `white-space: nowrap` so that your items do not float down. Set the width of the items accordingly. And then use JS/jQuery to process your slider. Or wait, you can actually use any existing JS slider!

Comment: Thank you, man! I have to change the position to absolute and instead of float: left to left: 0 and float: right to right: 0. Post your comment as an answer. You deserve some reputation!

Comment: Glad that it helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find plenty of examples for the same.

The logic is simple: Put your arrows with absolute position to left and right of images' container. In your images' container, set `white-space: nowrap` so that your items do not float down. Set the width of the items accordingly. And then use JS/jQuery to process your slider. Or wait, you can actually use any existing JS slider!

Some nice sliders are:

http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo4

http://www.jssor.com/